# Why is the page number not assigning as "?page=2" to the Laravel route in blade?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

My route is:

```
Route::get('/posts/{id}', 'PostsController@index')->name('posts.index');
```

And my blade view is:

```
{{route('posts.index', $id, ['page' => Request::get('page')])}}
```

Even when I am on the second page of the pagination the above blade code does not assign the page number to the URL, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this

```php
{{route('posts.index', ['id'=>$id,'page' => Request::get('page')])}} // here `id` is your route param it may change is u use resource route you can verify to run 

php artisan route:list
```

as `route()` 2nd parameter is all the params so u can't give 3rd parameter

ref link https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/helpers#method-route

Comment: Thank you! I was just about to make a mess writeing: `{{route('posts.index', $id}} {!! Request::get('page') ? '?page='.Request::get('page') : '' !!}` Your answer is much more efficient and clean, thanks!

Comment: @Emmanuel-Ab mark this answer if it solve your problem thank you